# Binary scan tcl

Tags: binary, tcl, eof

I have problem with my code because of not all line from file are scanning .

It stopped after 1000 attempt. I am trying to scan all binary lines from wav  file. When binary scan starts to return important value for me I don't know why eof occur (a lot bytes left to read).

```
    set fh [open $file r]
    binary scan [read $fh 12] A4iA4 sig1 len sig2
    if {$sig1 != "RIFF" || $sig2 != "WAVE"} { 
        close $fh; 
        return -code error "Not a WAV file" 
    }
    binary scan [read $fh 24] A4issiiss id size format channels samplerate byterate align bitrate
    binary scan [read $fh 8] A4i data sampletoread
    set len [expr {[file size $file] - [tell $fh] - 8 - ($size - 16)}]
    set str [ list ]
    while {1} {
        if {[eof $fh]} break
        binary scan [read $fh 1000] c* str
        puts "$str"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've opened the file in text mode, not binary mode, so input stops at the first `^Z` character (which is the official ASCII text EOF character; this is in fact useful in some use-cases, though not in yours). Since you're reading binary data, you should open it as such by passing the `b` open mode flag:

```
set fh [open $file rb]
```

If you're using an older version of Tcl, you instead (and equivalently) do:

```
set fh [open $file r]
fconfigure $fh -translation binary
```

The `b` flag is just a (very) convenient shortcut. (The second way works on all Tcl versions back to 8.0; you didn't want to handle binary data at all in Tcl directly before then.)